# Last expect instruction is not executed

Tags: linux, bash, expect, cisco-ios

I'm working on a script to automatize instructions on an IOS Cisco router, using the expect commands.

Here is the script I wrote:

```
#!/bin/expect
#log_user 0
set timeout 60

set mode [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh myuser@10.0.0.254


expect "*assword:" {
    send "mypassword\r"
}

expect "*>" {
    send "enable \r"
}

expect "*#" {
    send "conf t \r"
}

expect "*(config)" {
        send "interface Serial0/0/0 \r"
        send "clock rate 14400\r"
}
```

My problem is, this script stops at the "router1(config)#" state.
But if I put an `interact` command at the end of my script, all of this is working correctly. The user correctly get into the interface config mode and the clock rate is well updated.
But the fact is, I don't want the user to interact.

So I really do not understand what is going on and why I cannot just end the script like that...

If you have any clues... ?

Comment: run your script with `expect -d` and examine the debugging output to see if your patterns are matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my issue by myself.

It's a bit cheaty but... well it works.

Given that it's the last `expect` command which does not work, I've added a last "useless expect" at the end of my script :

```
expect "*(config)" {
        send "interface Serial0/0/0 \r"
}
expect "*(config-if)" {
        send "clock rate 14400\r"
}
expect "*(config-if)" {
        send "end"
        close
}
```

Anyway, if someone has a proper way to do it, I'm still open

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Your *send* too quickly and does not wait for the `ssh` process to *exit*.

Comment: Yes, but even if I had a *sleep 5* at the end of the script, it still does not work...